# My Catalog list has no effect on the home page

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, product-list

I have a personalized **list.phtml** within the "**Magento_Catalog**" module of my theme, the changes there take effect on the category page, but not on the "Catalog products list" widget that I put on the home page.
My question, how do I get my personalization to appear in the home widget?

app/design/frontend/Vendor/xxx/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
?>
<div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
        <li class="item product product-item">
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                <?php
                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                if ($pos != null) {
                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                }
                ?>
                <?php // Product Image ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                   class="product photo product-item-photo"
                   tabindex="-1">
                    <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                </a>
                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                    <?php
                        $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                    ?>
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link"
                           href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                            <?php
                            $nome = $_product->getName();
                            $flgg=false;
                            if(strpos(strtoupper($nome),"RRRR")!== false){
                                $dados = explode("RRRR", strtoupper($nome));
                                $nameBold = $dados[0]."RRRR";
                                $nome = $dados[1];
                            }else{
                               $flgg = true;
                                $noome=$nome;
                            }


                            ?>
                            <?=($flgg)? /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $noome, 'name'):/* @noEscape */ '<a style="
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Bree-Lt;
    ">'.$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $nameBold, 'name').' </a>'.'<a style="
        font-family: Bree-Lt;
    ">'.$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $nome, 'name').'</a>' ?>

                        </a>
                    </strong>
                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>


                    <div class="product-item-inner">
                        <div class="bloquinhoImg">
                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        </br>

                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                            <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                    <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                          data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                          method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden"
                                               name="product"
                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                <?php else :?>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                    <?php else :?>
                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')) :?>
                                    <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if ($showDescription) :?>
                            <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                   title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                   class="action more"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) :?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In category**

[image]

---

**In home...**

[image]

Comment: Your first step is to confirm you've altered the tenplate for the widget. Chuck a die('catalog template'); in the php and if it doesn't affect the homepage go find the widget tenplate...

Comment: Sorry I think I couldn't understand what you meant, but investigating I found in vendor "module-catalog-widget", I put in my theme as, "Magento_Catalog_Widget" and put it inside ... / content / grid.phtml o even though I edited in list but it still didn't reflect anything in the home widget.

Comment: That is what I was suggesting you do, work through the templates until you find the correct widget template. Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml most likely isn't the template for that widget.

Comment: Make sure you've also set the theme in the widget settings in the admin.

Comment: Ok I understand your suggestion, the theme is active yes. I'll continue searching. Thank you!